# Identify bottleneck while training model using tensorflow2

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, debugging

I'm new to Tensorflow. I would like to identify which part of my model training is taking time: whether it's the data load or forward pass through the model.
In pytorch, I could just comment the forward pass,  loss computation and the backward pass, which are under the for loop for the number of epochs, and get an idea of how much time data loader is taking.
However,  in TF. I'm pretty much stuck or hit a wall with model.fit.generator.

Any idea how I can achieve a similar bottleneck analysis?

Comment: Probably you are using the `ImageDataGenerator` class with `fit_generator`. It's not too fast, you need to use tf.data API if you want to see some speed-up.

Comment: Tensorboard does _exactly_ that

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras#debug_performance_bottlenecks